# Python list index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I have the following table

```
    userid  eventid urlclick
0   A   EID-1   [0, 2, 2, 4, 0]
1   A   EID-2   [1, 0, 2, 5, 1]
```

And my goal is to get the index of the particular value for urlclick column to have the result as

```
userid  eventid urlclick    urlclick_ind
0   A   EID-1   [0, 2, 2, 4, 0] [0, 4]
1   A   EID-2   [1, 0, 2, 5, 1] [1]
```

I achieved it using the following code. But is there a better way to do it?

```
new_ind = []
for row in time1.urlclick:
    ind = 0
    indlst = []
    for element in row:
        if element == 0:
            indlst.append(ind)
        ind += 1
    
    new_ind.append(indlst)

time1['urlclick_ind'] = new_ind
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try `np.where`:

```
np.where(np.array([0, 2, 2, 4, 0]) == 0)[0].tolist()
np.where(np.array([1, 0, 2, 5, 1]) == 0)[0].tolist()
```

output:

```
[0, 4]
[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You might use `enumerate` and `list` comprehension for this task as follows

```
def find_zeros(row):
    return [inx for inx,i in enumerate(row) if i==0]

print(find_zeros([0, 2, 2, 4, 0]))
print(find_zeros([1, 0, 2, 5, 1]))
```

output

```
[0, 4]
[1]
```